# Conditions equivalent to uniform convergence of infinite product of functions

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence, infinite-product

Let $(f_n(z))$ be sequence of complex functions.

By definition, infinite product $\prod f_n$ converges uniformly if there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $F_N(z):=\lim_{m\to \infty} \prod_{n=N}^{m} f_n(z)$ is uniformly convergent and $F_N(z)$ has no zeros.

I want to show that uniform convergence of infinite product $\prod f_n$ is equivalent to the following two conditions:

(1)$f_n(z)$ converges uniformly to 1 as $n\to \infty$;this implies that, for sufficiently large n, the principal branch of the logarithm of $f_n$ can be defined.

(2)For sufficiently large n, $\sum \log f_n$ is uniformly convergent series.

Is this claim correct?If so, how can I prove it?

The proof is possible in the case of a sequence of complex numbers instead of a sequence of functions.

Comment: Your definition is a bit weird but the essential is that in the given domain (usually a compact) only finitely many $f_n$ have zeroes and $f_n \to 1$ uniformly so one can indeed find a large $N$ for which we can define $\log f_m$ by the power series of $\log (1+u_m)$ where $|u_m|=|f_m-1| <1/2$ say on the domain for all such $m$; then the logarithm of any partial product from then on can be defined as the sum of the previous functions and indeed the result holds since the first $N-1$ terms do not matter for convergence and can be multiplied at the end with the result from $N$ on